# how to solve badly formed lambda in lisp?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I am trying to check if a list has a mountain aspect or not in lisp.
e.g:1,5,9,6,4,3

l is my list and aux is 0-the ascending part of l or 1-the descending part of the list.
muntemain  just call munte starting with aux=0,the ascending part

my error is :

```
 Badly formed lambda: (AND (< (CAR L) (CAR (CDR L))) (EQ AUX 0))
```

and I can't see the problem.Can someone help please?

```
(defun munte (l aux)
      (cond 
          ((and (atom l) (null aux)) NIL)
          ((and (null l) (null aux)) NIL)
          ((and (atom l) (eq aux 1)) T)
          ((and (null l) (eq aux 1) T)
          ((and (< (car l) (car(cdr l))) (eq aux 0)) (munte(cdr l) 0))
          ((and (or (> (car l) (cadr l)) (= (car l) (cadr l))) (eq aux 0))(munte(cdr l) 1))
          ( and (> (car l) (cadr l)) (eq aux 1)) (munte(cdr l) 1))
          (T NIL)
)
)

(defun muntemain (l)
(cond 
         ((> (car l) (cadr l)) NIL)
         ((< (length l) 2) NIL)
         (T (munte l 0))
)
)
```

Comment: You're missing a close parenthesis after `(eq aux 1)` on the line before that. You're also missing an open parenthesis before `and` on the line before `(T NIL)`. Use an editor with parenthesis matching and automatic indentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Formatting

As [noted by Barmar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34166445/how-to-solve-badly-formed-lambda-in-lisp#comment56081249_34166445), you really need to use an editor to help you with the parenthesis. There are many tutorials for installing Emacs+Slime. Take some time to install proper tools.

#### Don't use [`EQ`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/lw51/CLHS/Body/f_eq.htm) for numbers and characters

> An implementation is permitted to make "copies" of characters and
>   numbers at any time. The effect is that Common Lisp makes no guarantee
>   that eq is true even when both its arguments are "the same thing" if
>   that thing is a character or number.

#### Factorize tests

```
    ((and (atom l) (null aux)) NIL)
    ((and (null l) (null aux)) NIL)
    ((and (atom l) (eq aux 1)) T)
    ((and (null l) (eq aux 1) T)
```

From the definition of [`atom`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_atom.htm), `NIL` is an atom, so you don't need `(null L)`. The different cases for `aux` can be grouped too. The clause below is sufficient to account for all the above ones:

```
    ((atom L) (eql aux 1))
```

But I don't understand why `aux` is not a boolean in the first place if you always bind it to 0 or 1. Just use `t` and `nil` and return `aux` in the above clause.

#### Use meaningful functions

```
(< (car l) (car(cdr l)))
```

Of course, `(car(cdr ..))` is known as `(cadr ..)`, but also as `second`. The above test is equivalent to:

```
(< (first L) (second L))
```

And what if your list has *no second element*? You will compare a number against `nil` and signal an error (not what you want). You need more tests. In `muntemain`, you seem to have a special case for when length is below 2, but the test is done only if the previous returns `nil`, which won't happen if an error is signaled.

#### An iterative alternative

Here is a completely different way to attack the problem, just to give you ideas.

```
(lambda (list)
  (loop
    ;; memories
    for px = nil then x
    for pdx = nil then dx

    ;; current element
    for x in list

    ;; first and second "derivatives" (signs only)
    for dx = 1 then (signum (- x px))
    for ddx = 0 then (signum (- dx pdx))

    ;; checks
    sum ddx into total
    always (and (<= dx 0) (<= -1 total 0))
    finally (return (= total -1))))
```

Comment: Thanks.I changed the code with first and second and now it compiles without errors

Comment: @PădureanFlorina-Alexandra That's great, keep going. If the answer is good for you, you are encouraged do "accept" it (green checkmark).